# SP2013 List: Trigger JQuery to run with each list view change or to/from Quick Edit mode

Tags: jquery, quick-edit, internal-name

I am using a JQuery script in a list (in a Script Editor) to (visually) change a column's name. The internal and display column names remain static.

When I switch from normal view to Quick Edit, the JQuery fails to relaunch and I lose the column name change.

Is there a way to trigger JQuery to run with each view change or moving back and forth into/from Quick Edit mode?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#js-listviewthead-WPQ2").find('tr>th').each(function(){
            if($(this).find('div').attr("displayname")=="Prev Month")
            {
                    $(this).find('a:first').text("Prev EOM 03-31-2021");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**To insert a script that always runs when a view is refreshed**

The only right way of injecting JavaScript to SharePoint lists/views is to use the JSLink / Client Side Rendering (CSR). [Check out the fantastic article on this by Andrei Markeev](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views).

This is how you run your script reliably, without any script webparts:

- Install [Cisar Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en)
- Navigate to the SharePoint list
- Click F12
- Click Cisar tab
- Click on the "**Click here to add a file to the webpart**"
- Type a file name of your choice
- Press Enter:

[image]

- Uncomment the "OnPostRender" function and inject your code here:

[image]

[image]

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

  function getBaseHtml(ctx) {
    return SPClientTemplates["_defaultTemplates"].Fields.default.all.all[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.FieldType][ctx.BaseViewID](ctx);
  }

  function init() {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({      
      OnPostRender: function(ctx) { 
        $("#js-listviewthead-WPQ2").find('tr>th').each(function(){
            if($(this).find('div').attr("displayname")=="Prev Month")
            {
                    $(this).find('a:first').text("Prev EOM 03-31-2021");
            }
         });
        },
      ListTemplateType: 100

    });
  }

  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/ViewScript.js"), init);
  init();

});
```

**You can also add the JS Link manually.**

- Edit the page
- Go to the webpart properties
- Specify the JSLink like so:

[image]

Comment: Denis, thank you for the detailed answer!  I work for a bank and there are restrictions on not only viewing images on this site but downloading Chrome extensions.  I managed to see your images on my personal laptop.
That all being said, is it possible to save this script in my doc library and put a reference url to the script into the JS Link?

Comment: Sure! Every list or a view has a JSLink property. So you have to 1) Manually create and upload a JS file to a library and 2) In your list or library or a View, in the JSLink property specify the URL. See my updated answer.

Comment: Perfect!  So, I have one more question because I'm not fluent in JS or JQ. Am I placing your code as-is into the JS Link or adding it below the standard script :<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

If I was using a script editor or CEWP, I would paste in a standard JS script but I'm not sure with a JS Link script.

Comment: You don't need the script tag and the ready function. You can just use my script. Just make sure that `~siteCollection/Style Library/ViewScript.j` part is replaced with your library/list URL and the script name.

Comment: OK. Mine are stored as txt files so I'm assuming that extension will be fine.

Comment: you can rename txt to js. but maybe .txt will work too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123239/discussion-between-chasepes-and-denis-molodtsov).